# How to find arc angle with known other arc?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Take a look at the draft, please.
I need to build **arc**1 from one point to another with given radius. For this i need to know *start* and *end* angles **a4** and **a5**. This is the requirements of programming library i use.

I suppose i can find **a5** easely as `a4 + 2*a1`. So the question is how to find **a4**.

[image: Click to open Draft]

Ark width **w**, length of perpendicular **p** to the **w**, angles **a1** and **a2**, and radius **r** are known. Angle a3 is 90 degrees.

Coordinate system of this circle starts from right and goes clockwise. In this particular case on the draft start of the arc will be 195°, end 95°.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $a_5 = 360^\circ - (a_4 + 2a_1)$

Now, beyond that, I was about to say there simply is not enough information to determine a specific $a_4$ or $a_5$.  Put another way, that triangular wedge can slide all around that circle and be located anywhere.

*But then* I read you last sentence "In this particular case on the draft start of the arc will be 195°, end 95°."  I find this way of phrasing it to be confusing, but it sounds like either $a_4$ or $a_5$ must be $95^\circ$, and it looks like $a_4 \approx 95^\circ$ in the draft.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry for confusion. "195° and 95°" is only valid for this particular draft for example. There are no guaranty a4 and a5 will be always 45° each. By the way. If there are no enough information, i will look what else i can get to solve this task.

Comment: I will wait for some one other who confirm there are no way to solve this before accept this answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

My question in origin has no solutions, this is why i accept @bob.sacamento answer. But in practice, as soon i build all shapes by self, i can calculate **a4** as angle of SSS triangle. Two sides of this triangle are radius length, and third (opposite to **a4** can be calculated. From there `a4 = arcos(b^2 + c^2 - a^2 / 2bc)`.

[Click to see draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqW7B.png)